# Javascript Append Link on Copy

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added Javascript Append link on copy in my blog, means when someone copy text from my site, it will also copy blog post url and add read more tag, so i want to modify this script, and make it like, when someone copy minimum 20 character, then this code will copy read more tag in clipboard, if user copy less than 20 words, then this script should not work. so if anyone can make it happen, it will be great helpful.
Thanks

Original Script -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addLink() {
    var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var selection;
    selection = window.getSelection();
    var pagelink = "<br /><br /> Read more at: <a href='"+document.location.href+"'>"+document.location.href+"</a><br />"; // change this if you want
    var copytext = selection + pagelink;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.style.position='absolute';
    newdiv.style.left='-99999px';
    body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
    },0);
}
document.oncopy = addLink;
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this. Whenever the length of the selection is less than 20 , the function will return the selection.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addLink() {
    var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var selection;
    selection = window.getSelection();
    if(selection.toString().length<20)
     {
       return selection;
      }
    var pagelink = "<br /><br /> Read more at: <a href='"+document.location.href+"'>"+document.location.href+"</a><br />"; // change this if you want
    var copytext = selection + pagelink;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.style.position='absolute';
    newdiv.style.left='-99999px';
    body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
    },0);
}
document.oncopy = addLink;
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi  Sooraj Chandran, Thanks for answering, But after use your code, when i copy less Than 20 Characters from site, it's not even copying that 20 characters. So please modify it so it can copy less than 20 characters, but if try to copy more than 20 character, then shows a read more tag.

Comment: Thanks a ton dude. you made my day